# A visual riddle about an artifact

Tags: riddle, visual, knowledge

[image: You won't find the answer here]

Can you explain (all numbers) what/who I am?

**Note**:

> The order of the numbers doesn't matter.

Comment: Awesome puzzle.  Had me pulling my hair out!  First one like it I've seen.  The more of these the better!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are a ...

> ... scarab.

Image 1:

> A sand dune. [Andrew's dune scarab beetle](http://www.biologicaldiversity.org/species/invertebrates/Andrews_dune_scarab_beetle/) is an endangered species of beetles in Southern California.

Image 2:

> A racing car. More precisely, a [1958 Scarab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarab_(constructor)).

Image 3:

> Herakles or **Hercules** as seen by Disney. The [Hercules beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_beetle) is a beetle of the *Scarabaeidae* family.

Image 4:

> A British made three-wheeled tractor, the [Scammell Scarab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scammell_Scarab). (The name is not a reference to scarabs, but a contraction of Scammell and Arab horse, though.)

Image 5:

> A sunrise. The Egyptian god [Khepri](http://www.landofpyramids.org/khepri.htm) was the solar god of the sunrise and is often depicted as human with a scarab's head.

Image 6:

> An Egyptian mummy. In Ancient Egypt, [scarab amulets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarab_(artifact)) were sometimes used as burial objects. The puzzle's title is an allusion to such artefacts.

Comment: Well done! and so quick :)